# Multiple optional query parameters in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express and I have a route which makes a GET request to my 'challenges' collection in MongoDB. This will find a specific challenge based on the section number and challenge number.

My code is as follows:

```
// @route           GET api/challenge?section=_&challenge=_
// @description     Get challenge by section number and challenge number
// @access          Private

router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const challenge = await Challenge.find({
      section_no: req.query.section,
      challenge_no : req.query.challenge,
    });

    if (!challenge) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Challenge not found' });
    }

    return res.json(challenge);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

Now this works fine when querying it on Postman. When I enter both query param values 'section' & 'challenge' I get the desired result and it is able to return that particular challenge data.

But my question is:

How can I modify this code so that I can optionally query ONLY section OR BOTH section & challenge. So for example, if I was to query the following:

```
api/challenge?section=1
```

It would return all data on all challenges in section 1

But I still want to be able to return a specific challenge by using the query:

```
api/challenge?section=1&challenge=1
```

And it would return all data on the first challenge in section 1

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to use the spread operator, since the keys are the same as database query:

```js
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const challenge = await Challenge.find({
      ...req.query,
    });

    if (!challenge) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Challenge not found' });
    }

    return res.json(challenge);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

In this case, note that query should have the keys "challenge_no" and "section_no" or, the inverse, query should support "challenge" and "section" keys from the query object.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a filter object where you put your query strings if exists here is what the code looks like:

```
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const filter = {};
    if (req.query.section) filter.section_no = req.query.section;
    if (req.query.challenge) filter.challenge_no = req.query.challenge;

    const challenge = await Challenge.find(filter);

    if (!challenge) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Challenge not found' });
    }

    return res.json(challenge);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

Comment: This is also a great answer, thank you for taking the time to help!